# Writing update Query in wordpress for a custom field in General setting TAB

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, image-uploading

I want to add a custom field in General setting TAB in wordpress.
This are the present fields that wordpress has it by default.

1. Site Title
2. Tag line
3. Wordpress Address URL
   ...etc

I want to add a custom field like, I want to have an image upload field.
To achieve this I have edited my function.php file. This is my code.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_settings_wpse_57647' );

    # Register settings
    function register_settings_wpse_57647() 
    {
        register_setting( 
            'general', 
            'html_guidelines_message',
            'esc_html'
        );
        add_settings_section( 
            'site-guide', 
            'Logo', 
            '__return_false', 
            'general' 
        );
        add_settings_field( 
            'html_guidelines_message', 
            'Upload your Store Logo', 
            'upload_image_function', 
            'general', 
            'site-guide' 
        );
    }    

    # Print settings field content
    function upload_image_function() 
    {?>

         <input type='file' name='file'> 
    <?php }
    // ends
```

This code shows the upload field in my general settings. I want to update the table **`wp-options`** in my database which has **`option_name`** as logo to some **`option_value`** i.e image name, as I checked the **`options-general.php file`**   the form action takes me to **`option.php`** page. I have tried putting a normal php script using  **`isset($_POST['submit'])`** function but it doesn't work.

Does core PHP code works in WP environment  Or I'm missing on something, Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

To save an image directly in the wordpress database option table, you'll have to alter the table to allow images, which is not recommended and not a solution(your settings and code will break when you update wordpress).

What you can do: create a place in the admin (like an settings page or whatever you want) where you allow an administrator to upload the file you want to upload, then save the file in a specific theme/plugin/site folder and just save the image link in the options table using [`update_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) and to get the value you use [`get_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)